# Threejs, pointLight not rendering

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I've made a sphere and now I'm adding lighting to it. Directional lighting works fine, but point and spot lighting don't show up. Anyone know why only some lights work?

```
let renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
container.append( renderer.domElement );

const scene = new Scene();
scene.background = new Color( 'black' );

const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
let camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 35, aspect, 0.1, 100 );
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

var drLight = new DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
drLight.position.set( 3, 2000, 2000 );
camera.add( drLight );

var pLight = new PointLight( 0x8564cc, 0.5 );
pLight.position.set( 200, 500, 200 );
camera.add( pLight );

var sLight = new SpotLight( 0xff0000 );
sLight.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
camera.add( sLight );

scene.add( camera );

// Create sphere
const geometry = new SphereGeometry( 15, 32, 16 );
const material = new MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: new Color( 0x3a228a ),
    shininess: 0.7
} );

const sphere = new Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you for the reply! however I've tried both and none of them worked. I used the helper and could see the lines, only thing that worked was setting the intensity to 90000000, it doesn't seem like the right approach tho, and I still don't know why it acts like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lighting has changed in `r155`. The details of this change are explained in this guide: [Updates to lighting in three.js r155](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/updates-to-lighting-in-three-js-r155/53733)

In short, point lights behave physically correct now and use candela as a unit. That requires a real-world scale for your scene meaning 1 world unit should be considered as 1 meter.

When migrating existing applications, the new lighting usually means you have to apply much higher intensity values to point lights especially if your scene has a large scale or when point lights are positioned far away from objects.

You can also set the `decay` property of your point light to `0` although it means it won't behave physically correct then.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I did figure out the intensity value had to be super high, but I couldn't understand why when other projects I've seen didn't need it! Glad it wasn't me who did something very wrong.